# buy one get one free Ubercart discount module?

Tags: ubercart

Can I use some module to make offers in ubercart
I have to make an offer of 2x1 type (buy one, get one free)
or buy 2 and get 1 free type of offers

Comment: hello did you solved this, without any issue, please reply? I have an issue, discount not apply on review setting if i change the payment method. Review at http://drupal.org/node/1948732

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [Ubercart Discounts (Alternative)](http://drupal.org/project/uc_discounts_alt) can do you you ask:

> ### **Features**
>
> 1. Filter both products required for the discount to apply and qualifying products that receive the discount based on multiple products, taxonomy terms, node authors, or product classes.
> 2. The above filters allow for a discount like: **buy 3 of any of X product and get a discount on any of Y product**.
> 3. Attempts to automatically add free products to the cart for codeless discounts.
>      Discount # of products, a percentage or a fixed amount off.
> 4. ...

I don't have any personal experience with the module, but it looks promising.