# How can I do "Buy one get two free" with Ubercart?

Tags: 6, ubercart

For example the firs item is $3 and the second one & the third one are $0. Can I do this?
Maybe [Ubercart Discounts (Alternative)](http://drupal.org/project/uc_discounts_alt) can do the result but I don't want to show the discount price and just want to show the second and the third item $0 on the cart page.

Comment: Check out [buy one get one free Ubercart discount module?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19855/buy-one-get-one-free-ubercart-discount-module)

Comment: The OP is asking for an alternative to the Ubercart Discounts (Alternative) module, which is the only solution reported in the other question. Alternatively, if that is the only module available, the OP is interested to show the result in a different way (e.g. without show the discount price).

Comment: The problem using "Ubercart Discounts (Alternative)" is that in the cart pane I don't want to show the price of the discounted item but just simply as "$0" for the secound and the third item. Also I don't want to show the "sub total" or "Total discount" but only the final amount after discounted.Basically what want to do is simply make the second and the third products free for this product type without charging once and then discounting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using [Ubercart Custom Price](http://drupal.org/project/uc_custom_price) module and the code below.

```
// Load the current shopping cart.
      $items = uc_cart_get_contents($cid = NULL, $action = NULL);


    // Count the number of items
      $number_of_items = count($items);

    $firstPrice = 10;
    $secondPrice = 0;
    $thirdPrice = 0;

    switch ($number_of_items) {
      case 0:
        $item->price = $firstPrice;
        break;

      case 1:
        $item->price = $secondPrice;
        break;

     case 2:
        $item->price = $thirdPrice;
        break;
    }
```